# Downloading web image w/ urlopen/shutil : error __exit__

Tags: python, download, urlopen, shutil, webimage

I'm trying to download images with shutil/urlopen because of deprecated? I'm not sure if its deprecation, but urlretrieve doesn't download the file, it just creates folder of the image name instead. After looking at other question I saw one that provides this code, but I get an error on this one too.

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from shutil import copyfileobj


url = 'http://www.watchcartoononline.com/thumbs/South-Park-Season-14-Episode-11-Coon-2-Hindsight.jpg'
path = 'image.jpg'

with urlopen(url) as in_stream, open(path, 'wb') as out_file:
    copyfileobj(in_stream, out_file)
```

output

```
with urlopen(url) as in_stream, open(path, 'wb') as out_file:
AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no attribute '__exit__
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve("http://url/img.jpg", "img.jpg")
```

Comment: as I said in the question, urlretrieve won't work because the site im downloading from has its images deprecated

Comment: @Crispy: Are you sure deprecated is the word you're looking for?

Comment: I'm probably wrong with the term, as my terminology in programming isn't very good.

Comment: @Crispy if you need to download the file, use this solution. I'm uncertain on what you mean by deprecated, but `urlretrieve` is almost equivalent to what you are doing there.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to use urlretrieve, it works now. I was making a directory of my image name on accident

Answer (score 2):

`urlopen` does not implement a context manager, so you cannot use it in a `with` block. Here is the [bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue12955).

You could use `contextlib.closing` to wrap it, although the bug report above mentions some issues with that too.

NOTE: this applies only to Python < 3.2

Answer (score 1):

`urlopen` isn't a context manager in Python 2 (I don't know about 3). You have to manually open and close it:

```
in_stream = urlopen(url)

with open(path, 'wb') as out_file:
    copyfileobj(in_stream, out_file)

in_stream.close()
```

You can also just use `urllib.urlretrieve`:

```
import urllib

urllib.urlretrieve(url, path)
```

It reads/writes in chunks, which lets you download large files cleanly.